# 2 of each Tetris Puzzle

Tags: geometry, tiling

In [Is this Tetris puzzle solvable?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/is-this-tetris-puzzle-solvable) we established that it is not possible to form a rectangle with an uneven number of each Tetris piece.

But if we had a solution for 2 of each piece, we would now that it works with any even number of each piece, because we could just stack the 2 of each solution.

**Question:** Is it possible to form a rectangle with 2 of each Tetris piece and if yes what would your solution look like?

[image: Tetris pieces]

Note: I have previously answered this question in the wrong place at [Is this Tetris puzzle solvable?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/is-this-tetris-puzzle-solvable) so if you can see deleted answers, please don't answer and let the other users have some fun with this!

Comment: "I'll accept the first solution by a below 2k rep user." - finally, a question that rand al'thor can't answer! (Just saying it before someone else does) :-P

Comment: @randal'thor Sorry to exclude you but don't you think it's boring when you can just look up the answer?

Comment: Don't worry, I don't mind! Not my kind of problem anyway. If I was going to try it, though, I wouldn't cheat! :-)

Comment: Is it within SE policy to give restrictions on who you accept answers from? I would accept the best answer regardless of the answerer.

Comment: @Deusovi I actually don't know whether we have a policy for that. Anyway, the downvotes suggest that the community doesn't like it, so I've removed that sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what size box you want them packed in, but based on the 7-wide in your other question, there is this option:

[image: 7x8 Grid]

Comment: I like this solution because it can be easily rearranged into a 4x14 by just splitting across the middle.