# Jumping on the Bandwagon

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

It seems like there's been a constant flow of new, and mostly questionable, number sequence puzzles popping up on the site recently.  My turn to add to the proverbial three-ring circus!

> $0, 9, 5, 1, 6, 0, 1, 15, 2, 17, 21, 4, ...$

What are the next $3$ values in this series?

*Now I know many of these have been roundly panned for being Bad Puzzles™—some even by me—so before anyone reaches for the down-vote, flag or vote-to-close buttons, rest assured that I know [What Not To Do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do) in a Number Sequence Puzzle. I've been circumspect in creating this sequence puzzle, and believe it is solvable, uniquely, given what I've provided here. Have fun!*

**—HINTS—**

*helpfulness level 0:*

> Technically, this could be solved by analyzing the numbers alone; but it's highly unlikely. So there are clues provided in the text.  (The link to [What Not To Do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do) was not gratuitous.)

*helpfulness level 1:*

> **[@wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/jumping-on-the-bandwagon#comment146452_48006)** and **[@DrnglVrgs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48439/30633)** have provided some highly relevant hints of their own.

*helpfulness level 2:*

> The title is completely irrelevant.  The text is not: there's a fundamental part of the puzzle "hiding" right out in the open.

*helpfulness level 3:*

> Related? [image: Two pieces of chocolate pie]

*helpfulness level 4:*

> Similar...   $\text{O E I S A 0 0 1 2 2 3}$

Comment: Can this be solved by analyzing the numbers alone, or are there necessary clues provided in the text?

Comment: @wildBillMunson That's a very good question. :)

Comment: Does the edit change the values?

Comment: @HerbWolfe No, or I would have reverted it.

Comment: I noticed you've used the words 'ring', 'roundly', and 'circumspect', all of which seem to indicate some kind of circular pattern. This seems to be the kind of well-embedded clue that you're known for... ;)

Comment: The sequence, in a strict mathematical sense, does not have a unique solution. Whether or not it is unique enough for the standards of this site, I don't know.

Comment: @CipherRiddle Quoting from the linked Meta post: "For any finite sequence of *n* real numbers, it is possible to create infinitely many polynomials that generate that sequence...."  So no, in a strict mathematical sense, no such enumerable sequence is unique. Having said that, there's a notion that [the "right" answer is the most "parsimonious" one—the one depending on the smallest number of "non-default" assumptions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45170/why-didnt-they-arrest-bob/45173#comment136108_45170). I'm looking for *that* answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next 3 values are :

> 19, 3, 7

Why ?

> Because the clues noticed by @wildBillMunson guided me on the way to Pi, which you confirmed with the 4th clue (and answer to @DrnglVrgs). Furthermore, the number three (3) appeared twice in the context, so it seemed to be important. (And it's been 27 days this question has been asked, as 27 = 3^3, this is ... oh, sorry, totally coincidental ;) )

So, how exactly ?

> I looked up in the decimal expansion of Pi the occurrences of 3, looking for anything good. It happened to me that the sequence number you provided is the number of *symbols* (and not digits because either I am totally wrong or the dot counts) between each of those occurrences of 3. Because I'm lazy, I got the pi sequence from [this website](http://mapage.noos.fr/echolalie/l127.htm) and wrote [this little Python code](http://pastebin.com/cB9mrxxp) to extract the next three digits.

Comment: Just so - nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

This answer should be at least 33% correct

> 18,36,4

The wild and probably wrong process:

> Divide the series in sets of three
> 0,9,5,
> 1,6,0,
> 1,15,2,
> 17,21,4
> The treat the columns separatedly, the middle one was the first:
> 9+6=15 15+6=21 21+15=36
>  the first column I followed the link you provided and arrived [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C1%2C17&language=english&go=Search)
> The last column was searching in the digits of pi (because you said circle a lot)

Comment: There's a single sequence here, not a union of radically different series formations. Nonetheless, at least 33% of your basic concepts were correct (though the specifics of what you did don't seem to be).

Comment: Interesting, thank you, will continue